# The remote server returned an error: (405) The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I want to update json file in Blob Storage on Azure, while `WebClient.uploadData(url,data)` it gives the error:

> The remote server returned an error: (405) The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb..

The code something like this:

```
    [Route("PostJsonData")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void PostJSONData(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = @"https://apkupdates.blob.core.windows.net/polaadapk/keywords.json";
            byte[] json1 = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json1);
            byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);

            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            Stream postStream = myWebClient.OpenWrite(url, "POST");
            postStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            myWebClient.UploadData(url, array);
            postStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gaurav already mentioned, you are using the wrong verb. However, I would highly recommend to use the existing **SDK** for .NET:

[Azure Storage APIs for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet)

The SDK also implements a exponential retry policy to handly transient errors (503 - Service Unavailble) which you otherwise have to implement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The correct HTTP verb for uploading is a blob is `PUT` and not `POST`. Because you're using `POST` instead of a `PUT` you're getting this error.

Please change the following line of code:

```
Stream postStream = myWebClient.OpenWrite(url, "POST");
```

to

```
Stream postStream = myWebClient.OpenWrite(url, "PUT");
```

And you should not get this `MethodNotAllowed (405)` error. Please note that you may get 403 error because the request is not authenticated. I would recommend reading [`Storage Service REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/azure-storage-services-rest-api-reference) documentation before proceeding.

Comment: I have use right now "PUT" instead of "POST" but its still not working..i will go through the Storage Service REST API Azure Ducumentation Thank You

Comment: Please edit your question and include the new error details. More than likely you’re getting a 403 error. As recommended by Martin, you should consider using Storage SDK instead of going REST API route. MIT would make things so much simpler for you.

Comment: now i got the diffrent Error      --The remote server returned an error: (400) An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified..